# Sorting a vector of unique_ptr in VS 2013

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, unique-ptr, playing-cards

I am attempting to make a `Deck` class that holds a vector of `unique_ptr<Card>`, but attempting to sort the vector results in this error:

> Error 1   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::
>       unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
>       : attempting to reference a deleted function

Looking through Stack Overflow, it looks like there is a bug in VS 2013 where vectors incorrectly tries to copy `unique_ptr`s instead of moving them, so I attempted to add my own move function to my `Deck` class, but I still get the error.

Here is a minimal example of the code in question (`Card` is just a dummy class, with no objects in it):

Deck.h:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Deck
{
public:
typedef std::unique_ptr<Card> cardPtr;

Deck();

Deck(Deck && other)
    : mDeck(std::move(other.mDeck))
{
}

Deck& operator=(Deck other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}

friend void swap(Deck& lhs, Deck& rhs);

void                                sortDeck();

private:
static bool                         compareCards(cardPtr A, cardPtr B);

private:
std::vector<cardPtr>                mDeck;
};
```

Deck.cpp:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <algorithm>


Deck::Deck()
{
}

void swap(Deck& lhs, Deck& rhs)
{
using std::swap;
swap(lhs.mDeck, rhs.mDeck);
}


bool Deck::compareCards(cardPtr A, cardPtr B)
{
return true; //dummy- normally would have logic here
}

void Deck::sortDeck()
{
std::sort(mDeck.begin(), mDeck.end(), compareCards); //bug happens here
}
```

Any ideas about how to fix this? I'm sure I must be missing something fairly obvious, but I have been beating my head against this and googling it for a fair amount of time now, and could use some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `compareCards` function takes the `unique_ptr`s by value, this won't work as they are not copyable (the `unique_ptr` copy constructor is implicitly deleted due to the presence of move constructors, a copyable `unique_ptr` wouldn't be very unique would it?).

Change it to

`bool compareCards(cardPtr const& A, cardPtr const& B);`

Comment: Doh! That was it, exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous function is possible and better in your situation. This will prevent having multiple class functions thus faciliates the whole thing.

```
void sortUniquePtrObjects()
{
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(),
               [&](const std::uniquePtr<ObjectName> &A, const std::uniquePtr<ObjectName> &B)
               {
                   return A->comparableItem() == B->comparableItem();
               });
}
```